# Batch Script to zip file using CMD batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip, 7zip

I was trying to run the following script to zip each file to an individual zip file of its own. The code was executed without errors, but it did not generate any zip files. Could anyone let me know why?

```bash
echo on
for /f "tokens=3,2,4 delims=/- " %%x in ("%date%") do set d=%%y%%x%%z
set data=%d%
Echo zipping...
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\output_%d%.zip" "C:\Test\*.*"
echo Done!
```

References:
https://www.get-itsolutions.com/script-to-zip-file-using-cmd-batch-file/

Comment: *7-Zip* is installed with a help (documentation) which describes for __Command Line Version__ the __Syntax__ and the __Commands__ and the __Switches__. Read these help pages in *7-Zip* help. Then open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and `if /?` and read the two output usage helps of the commands __FOR__ and __IF__. A single command line like `@for %%I in ("C:\Folder Path\*") do @if /I not "%%~xI" == ".zip" if not exist "%%~dpnI.zip" "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx=9 -- "%%~dpnI.zip" "%%I"` in the batch file could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution without using external software

```
echo on
for /f "tokens=3,2,4 delims=/- " %%x in ("%date%") do set d=%%y%%x%%z
set data=%d%
Echo zipping...
powershell -command "Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\Test\*.*' -DestinationPath 'C:\output_%d%.zip'"
echo Done!
```